# Не срабатывает clearInterval

Tags: javascript

Почему не срабатывает clearInterval в моем случае? Спасибо!

```
 document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  var animation;
  var count = 0;


 if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
    animation = setInterval(function() {
      count++;
      console.log(count);
    }, 1000);
  }
  else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
    clearInterval(animation);
  }
 };
```

Comment: Переменные существуют только в пределах функции, создаются только когда функция начинает выполняться, и уничтожаются когда функция завершается. Вам нужно создать глобальную переменную `animation`. (Переменная `count` попадает в замыкание функции прописанной внутри setInterval и потому остаётся существовать)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас переменная `var animation` определена локально в функции, поэтому она создаётся каждый раз при вызове `document.onkeydown`.

Вам необходимо её вынести во внешний код (глобальная переменная).

Comment: Да, понял, спасибо!!

Answer (score 1):

Ответ уже дали, и тут очевидно, что переменная `animation` определена локально в функции, поэтому после повтороного попадиния в функцию - значение теряется по причине того, что она локальна и видна только на протяжении работы функции и в момент запуска функции всегда создается заново. Я все же дам ответ, содержащий исправленный код:

```js
var animation;

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
    var count = 0;
    animation = setInterval(function() {
      count++;
      console.log(count);
    }, 1000);
  } else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
    clearInterval(animation);
  }
};
```

А также, ссылки для изучения:

- [Window clearInterval() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)
- [Window setInterval() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)
- [clearInterval](https://javascript.ru/clearinterval)
- [setInterval](https://javascript.ru/setinterval)
- [setInterval and how to use clearInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978560/5275890)

Функция `setInterval` после своего выполнения возвращает `intervalID`, остановить функцию `setInterval` можно при помощи функции `clearInterval`. В функцию `clearInterval` передается идентификатор действия, которе нужно остановить. При передаче некорректного `intervalID` в метод `clearInterval` - не инициируется ошибка, поэтому код продолжает исправно работать без каких-либо ошибок в консоли.

Comment: Спасибо большое!